# Enable m2e logging in JBoss Developer Studio 11

Tags: m2e, jboss-developer-studio

JBoss Developer Studio 11.1.0.GA.

I've added the http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ repository.
Installed m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)   1.8.1.20170728-1531 (picked the version that corresponds to the installed m2e version).
Closed JBDS.
In `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.1.20170728-1531.xml` changed STDOUT filter's and root logger's levels to DEBUG.
Started JBDS. Opened Maven Console. Did a Maven Update Project. Nothing in console. No 0.log file in the org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration directory.

What's wrong? If I remember correctly, this worked in JDBS 10.2.0.GA.

In workspace preferences there is a Maven -> Debug Output setting. AFAIK it does nothing, but I tried enabling it anyway - no effect.
Tried changing `<File>${org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir}/0.log</File>` to a fixed path - no effect.

Comment: `Maven -> Debug Output` - it enables debug output from Maven itself, it's the `-X` switch.

Comment: Request to enable m2e logging in JBDS by default: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-4665